# Is Trump projected to win the popular vote?

Tags: united-states, election, voting, president

Apparently all of the votes have not been counted yet.  Do projections show that Trump will win the popular vote once all votes have been counted for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Do projections show that Trump will win the popular vote once all votes have been counted for?

#### No, in fact, quite the opposite.

[The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/elections/forecast/president) estimates Clinton to have won the popular vote by around 1.3%.

[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/11/09/politics/donald-trump-hillary-clinton-popular-vote/) also predicts it, as well as [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/nov/09/hillary-clinton-popular-vote-electoral-college-donald-trump).

The final outcome was Trump 46.1%, Clinton 48.2%, a margin for Clinton of 2.1%, but Trump won a majority in the Electoral College and became President.